# Unexpected behaviour when piping to ls() in R?

Tags: r

This returns the name of every second object in the environment

```r
test <- ls()
c(FALSE, TRUE) %>% { test[.] }
```

But this doesn't (it produces a strange vector of `NA`s)

```r
c(FALSE, TRUE) %>% { ls()[.] }
```

Why doesn't the second method work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `ls()` can't "figure out" the current environment when it is called in a pipe. When you assign the `ls()` outside of a pipe, then call the vector explicitly, there is no searching for the environment. To get around this, just explicitly call the environment in `ls()`.

```
c(FALSE, TRUE) %>% ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)[.]
```