# Strange behaviour when piping to return() in R function?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Under certain circumstances, piping to `return()` doesn't appear to behave expectedly. To demonstrate, here are 4 cases

Suppose we define a function that `return`s the result of `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

string <- letters[1:9] %>% paste0(collapse="")

funct <- function(string) {
  
  return(string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH"))
  
}

funct(string)
# [1] "abcdHHHghi"
```

Now suppose we pipe to `return` - function works as expected

```
funct <- function(string) {
  
  string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %>% return(.)
  
}

funct(string)
# [1] "abcdHHHghi"
```

But if we add some arbitrary commands *after* the `return`, we **do not** get the expected output (`[1] "abcdHHHghi"`)

```
funct <- function(string) {
  
  string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %>% return(.)
  
  print('hi')
  
}

funct(string)
# [1] "hi"
```

Note that if we don't pipe to `return`, we **do** see the expected behaviour

```
funct <- function(string) {
  
  return(string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH"))
  
  print('hi')
}

funct(string)
# [1] "abcdHHHghi"
```

#### Question

What is causing this behaviour and how do we get `return` to return (as expected) when piped to?

#### Desired Output

```
funct <- function(string) {

  string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %>% return(.)

  print('hi')

}

funct(string)
```

should return `# [1] "abcdHHHghi"`

#### Note

Based on similarly strange behaviour when [piping to `ls()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57399342/5783745), I tried

```
funct <- function(string) {
  
  string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %>% return(., envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  print('hi')
  
}

funct(string)
```

but it did not help:

```
Error in return(., envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
multi-argument returns are not permitted
```

Comment: You can pass the `print` in between the pipe as well with `{}`  Here, it is returning the last statement

Comment: @akrun I don't think that's the issue. Note that when we do not get the expected output, we see `[1] "hi'` rather than the expected output `[1] "abcdHHHghi"`. The issue isn't how do we get `"hi"` (as well), but why aren't we seeing `[1] "abcdHHHghi"` when piping to `return`

Comment: My point is that you define it to a object and then return the object after the `print`

Comment: ` v1 <- string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %>% return(.); print('hi');v1}`

Comment: @akrun that works, but I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with the pipe - how come I see one result with `return(x)` and a different result with `x %>% return(.)`. They should do the same thing (I thought)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the pipe.  It is just that the last statement would be the output.  Here, it is the `print`

Comment: @akrun we don't have to worry about the last statement thought, `return` lazy evaluates and returns when it's told to, here it is without the pipe (note there's a print statement and the print statement doesn't affect what is returned) `funct <- function(string) {return(string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH"));print('hi')};funct(string)` (this returns `[1] "abcdHHHghi"` - it doesn't run the print statement)

Comment: I think if you pipe in to return, return is evaluated in “deeper” environment, not your functions environment.

Comment: @akrun Try these side by side. They should do the same thing. `funct <- function(string) {return(string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH"));print('hi')};funct(string)` returns `# [1] "abcdHHHghi"`, but `funct <- function(string) {string %>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %>% return();print('hi')};funct(string)` returns `# [1] "hi"`

Comment: @user5783745  I  got your point

Comment: The pipe’d return is no longer for funct, it’s for the environment magrittr evaluates your chain in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` faces some evaluation issue when it is on RHS of the chain. See this [github issue thread](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/32).

If you have to use `return` the safest way is to use

```
funct <- function(string) {
   return(string %>% stringr::str_replace_all("ef", "HHH"))
   print('hi')
}

funct(string)
#[1] "abcdHHHghi"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the OP's mentioned way

```
funct <- function(string) {

  return(string %>% string::str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH"))

  print('hi')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is discussed in the "tradeoffs" vignette in the current version of `magrittr`.  They give alternative versions of the pipe, `%!>%` with "eager" semantics and `%|>%` with "nested" semantics to handle this.  (The `%|>` pipe doesn't appear to be in `magrittr` currently, but it should be a fairly close match to the base pipe that was introduced recently.)

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

string <- letters[1:9] %>% paste0(collapse="")

funct <- function(string) {
    
    string %!>% str_replace_all(., "ef", "HHH") %!>% return(.)
    
    print('hi')
    
}

funct(string)
#> [1] "abcdHHHghi"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that `dplyr` gets the regular pipe from `magrittr` and re-exports it, but it doesn't get the eager pipe, so you'll need an explicit `library(magrittr)` here.