# pipe into return doesn't work as expected

Tags: r

The following chunks of code should be doing exactly the same thing, but the first chunk unexpectedly prints "We reach here?" also when x = 2, which shouldn't be the case (I hope it's obviosu what I mean).

**Chunk 1**

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- c(1,2,3)
output <- map(input, function(x) {
  print(x)
  if (x == 2) {
    return(x)
  }
  print('We reach here?')
  return(x)
})
```

**Output**

This output is as expected, as the string doesn't print when x = 2.

```
[1] 1
[1] "We reach here?"
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] "We reach here?"
```

**Chunk 2**

```
input <- c(1,2,3)
output <- map(input, function(x) {
  print(x)
  if (x == 2) {
    x %>% return() 
  }
  print('We reach here?')
  x %>% return()
})
```

**Output**

```
[1] 1
[1] "We reach here?"
[1] 2
[1] "We reach here?"
[1] 3
[1] "We reach here?"
```

What am I missing here? Is this a bug?

Comment: The short answer is that `return()` doesn't work like a normal R function. Even the base pipe doesn't work with an input on the righthand side like `x |> return()`. Sorry that I can't provide a long answer, it's definitely interesting to know why.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596950/strange-behaviour-when-piping-to-return-in-r-function

Comment: @AndS.:  thanks for spotting this.  I've marked this question as a dupe, and put most of my answer on the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return()` function jumps up a level.  But the magrittr pipe `%>%` pushes evaluation down a level using some tricky evaluation.  So piping into `return()` jumps back to where it started, instead of up a level from the function where you wrote it.

I would have expected the base pipe `x |> return()` to work, because it really should be identical to `return(x)` (whereas the magrittr pipe is only a partial simulation of that code).  However, it is not allowed for some reason.

Is this a bug?  It's a limitation of the magrittr pipe for sure.  I'm not sure if the magrittr documentation discusses it. (It does; see the edit below!) So avoid putting `return()` in a pipe, and just use

```
return(x)
```

Edited to add:

I looked carefully through the magrittr docs, and found that this is discussed in the "tradeoffs" vignette.  They give alternative versions of the pipe, `%!>%` with "eager" semantics and `%|>%` with "nested" semantics to handle this.  (The `%|>` pipe doesn't appear to be in magrittr currently, but it should match the base pipe fairly closely.)

```
input <- c(1,2,3)
output <- map(input, function(x) {
  print(x)
  if (x == 2) {
    x %!>% return() 
  }
  print('We reach here?')
  x %!>% return()
})
```

This prints the same output as your Chunk 1.

Comment: you can use `x |> (\(k) return(k))()` for the base pipe, but you still get the same issues as the magrittr pipe.