# Why is the `return` function not pipable inside functions in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)

func <- function() {
  return(1)
  return(2)
}

func_pipe <- function() {
  1 %>% return()
  return(2)
}

func()
# [1] 1

func_pipe()
# [1] 2
```

Why doesn't the `func_pipe` function stop at the first `return`?

Comment: may be of interest : https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/32

Comment: I assume its the same reason as in, e.g., `f = function() { f1 = function() return(1); f1(); return(2) }; f()`; `%>%` just returns 1 while `func_pipe` executes after that and it returns 2.

Comment: You'll find answers in the github link as well as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596950/strange-behaviour-when-piping-to-return-in-r-function

Comment: @alexis_laz Hm? No, your example returns `2`, and the nested function is in fact completely ignored (in your edited comment `f1` gets executed but the output is still ignored). Nothing to do with pipes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph (sorry, my unedited comment was wrong). Not aware how a pipe should/could work, but isn't it that `"%>%"(1, return)` just `return`s `return(1)` which is expectedly ignored (as with a "normal" function)? (Probably, a better example is `f = function() { f1 = function(x, f) return(f(x)); f1(1, return); return(2) }; f()`)