# Common functions that don't behave as expected with magrittr pipe?

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

There are some cases where the `magrittr` pipe (`%>%`) doesn't behave quite as may be expected, and that therefore take a little time to debug, generate reprex's, discuss, and eventually refactor.

E.g.

- [piping to `ls()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398452/unexpected-behaviour-when-piping-to-ls-in-r) and
- [piping to `return()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596950/strange-behaviour-when-piping-to-return-in-r-function)

#### Question

In the interest of proactively educating oneself, is there some compilation of known `base` (and perhaps tidy) R functions with which the pipe doesn't behave as one may expect?

#### Current solutions

- We can periodically read the [magrittr issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues) (and probably issues with other related tidy packages), and
- Read [relevant stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+pipe+unexpected).

Although these sources are somewhat disparate.

Is there a way to generate a list, or perhaps one is maintained somewhere, perhaps in documentation, on github, or elsewhere, so that it can be periodically reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t a way to generate such a list automatically, since you effectively need to know the *semantics* of a function to know why (and therefore whether) it would work inside a pipeline.

*As a heuristic*, any function that takes an `envir` parameter that’s set to a default (as in the case of `ls`, bit also `get`, `exists`, etc.) will behave oddly with pipes.

That said, if you understand how function evaluation works in R it is usually pretty obvious for most functions whether they will work. I therefore suggest reading up on the R model of evaluation. In particular, read the relevant chapters in Hadley Wickham’s [*Advanced R*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/):

- [Chapter 6 *Functions*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html)
- [Chapter 7 *Environments*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html)

And, potentially, parts of

- [Part IV *Metaprogramming*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/meta-big-picture.html)

To be fair, that’s a lot of material. But having a good handle of how function evaluation and scoping (environments) work in R is crucial for a solid understanding of R anyway. Metaprogramming is more advanced and it’s more important to be aware of its existence than to immediately have a solid understanding of it.